# Oracle SQL Developer Error: vendor code 1317

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to browse a MySQL database. When I browse table with Columns tab (shows table definitions), some of tables will display an Error Encountered dialog that says:

> Vendor code 1317

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of SQL Developer?

Might be worth asking this question on the [SQL Developer Forum on OTN](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260) as it is well supported by the Oracle SQL Developer team.

I had a quick search and the only thread I could find was this [one](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4073074&#4073074) in which one of the responses reports the same problem as you but unfortunately there is not a direct response to it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer doesn't support 5.1.x series of jdbc mysql connector... you need to set up sql developer to use mysql-connector-java-5.0.4 in driver settings. You better use this one, because I was having the issue even with mysql-connector-java-5.0.8

Answer (score 1):

To browse MYSQL DB with version Oracle SQL Developer (version 2.1.2.64) and avoid the above problem, you must use mysql/J connector: mysql-connector-java-5.0.4.

mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 or mysql-connector-java-5.1.* WILL NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

1317 seems to be the mySQL code for ER_QUERY_INTERRUPTED.
Maybe some sort of timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following link for the answer

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/intro.htm#CHDIEGDD

This is an excerpt from the above link:

> Database: Third Party JDBC Drivers
>
> The Third Party JDBC Drivers pane
>   specifies drivers to be used for
>   connections to third-party
>   (non-Oracle) databases, such as IBM
>   DB2, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, or
>   Sybase Adaptive Server. (You do not
>   need to add a driver for connections
>   to Microsoft Access databases.) To add
>   a driver, click Add Entry and select
>   the path for the driver:
>
> For IBM DB2: the db2jcc.jar and
>   db2jcc_license_cu.jar files, which are
>   available from IBM
>
> For MySQL: a file with a name similar
>   to mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar,
>   in a directory under the one into
>   which you unzipped the download for
>   the MySQL driver
>
> For Microsoft SQL Server or Sybase
>   Adaptive Server: jtds-1.2.jar, which
>   is included in the jtds-1.2-dist.zip
>   download
>
> For Teradata: tdgssconfig.jar and
>   terajdbc4.jar, which are included
>   (along with a readme.txt file) in the
>   TeraJDBC__indep_indep.12.00.00.110.zip
>   or
>   TeraJDBC__indep_indep.12.00.00.110.tar
>   download
>
> **Alternative: As an alternative to
>   using this preference, you can click
>   Help, then Check for Updates to
>   install the JTDS JDBC Driver for
>   Microsoft SQL Server and the MySQL
>   JDBE Driver as extensions.**
>
> To find a specific third-party JDBC
>   driver, see the appropriate Web site.
>   **For MySQL, use the MySQL 5.0 driver, not
>   5.1 or later, with SQL Developer release 1.5.**
>
> You must specify a third-party JDBC
>   driver or install a driver using the
>   Check for Updates feature before you
>   can create a database connection to a
>   third-party database of that
>   associated type. (See the tabs for
>   creating connections to third-party
>   databases in the Create/Edit/Select
>   Database Connection dialog box.)